# Nested Xpath Query for itemprop

Tags: xpath, domdocument

I want to get all nested elements that have an itemprop="review" within a div with itemprop="reviews-container".

I'm using xpath and was thinking something like this:

```
$xpath->query('//div[@itemprop="reviews-container"]/div[@itemprop="review"]')
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
'//div[@itemprop="reviews-container"]//div[@itemprop="review"]'
                                     ^^
                                 recursion
```